# Java - Removing object from array when it collides with player

Tags: java

Im working on a falling blocks game in java where you have to move the player around the screen to dodge the blocks. Whenever you get hit by a block, depending on the block  type, it will either decrease or increase a int in the player class. Im having the problem that when the player is hit by the block the int keeps going down until the now invisible block is offscreen. Basically I just need a way to check through a object array and when a object meets a specified condition such as (delete == true) it will set the current position of that block in the array to null.

Method for updating the block position:

```
public void dropFoods(int speed) {
    for (int x = 699 - speed; x >= 0; x--) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
            if(x > (699 - GUI.HEIGHT) - 10) {
                food[y][x] = null;
                continue;
            }
            food[y][x + speed] = food[y][x];
            food[y][x] = null;

        }
    }
}
```

Method for drawing the blocks (the food are the different types of blocks):

```
for(int x = 0; x < food.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < food[x].length; y ++) {
                Object o = food[x][y];
                if(o instanceof Apple) {
                    new Apple(x * 100, y - Apple.HEIGHT, g);            
                }
                if(o instanceof Burger) {
                    new Burger(x * 100, y - Burger.HEIGHT, g);          
                }
            }
}
```

Method for detecting collision with player:

```
if(Food.getHitBox().intersects(Player.hitBox())) {
        willDraw = false;
        Player.weight -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Please improve your naming conventions or explain your code better. I'm under the impression that "Food" as in "Food.getHitBox()" is an object but it's capitalized. Also, always use var-- over var -= 1

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more code and debugging result first.

```
if(Food.getHitBox().intersects(Player.hitBox())) {
        willDraw = false;
        Player.weight -= 1;
}
```

So when something gets hit by player, do you remove the Food object off the map? Because according to this code, you are not.

Comment: I am not, im asking how to remove a object from the array list (also the array list is in a different file than the collision method